# Update db table with an INT

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Okay I can't get this figured out.

I want a logged in user to update a row with an amount (INT), I keep getting the invalid parameter error as well as a Call to member function execute() on a non-object.

Here is the php and html that should update the db

```
<?php
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_client_info WHERE UCODE=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['btn-update-data']))
        {
            $purchasedata = $_POST['purchasedata']; 
            $cpurchasedata = $_POST['cpurchasedata'];


            if($cpurchasedata!==$purchasedata)
            {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-block'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                        <strong>Sorry!</strong>  Input Does Not Match. Make sure the details match. 
                        </div>";
            }
            else
            {

                $stmt = $user_home->register("INSERT INTO tbl_client_info (purchasedata) VALUES (?)");
                $stmt->execute(array(":purchasedata"=>$purchasedata));

                //

                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                        Okay, we have added data to your account.
                        </div>";
            }
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                No Sorry That Did Not Work, Try again
                </div>";

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Forgot Password</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Custom styling plus plugins -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/icheck/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Sweet Alert -->
  <script src="dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
  <!--.......................-->

  </head>



<body style="background:#f3f3f3;"> 

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="login_content" class="animate form">
        <section class="login_content">
          <form method="post">
            <h1>Purchase Data</h1>

            <div class='alert alert-success'>
            <strong>Hello </strong><?php echo $row['firstname'] ?>! //add more text here
        </div>

        <?php
        if(isset($msg))
        {
            echo $msg;
        }
        ?>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="500mb" name="purchasedata" required />
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Retype the bundle" name="cpurchasedata" required />
        <hr />
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-update-data">Add data to my account</button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="separator">
```

and here is the class_user.php

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function lasdID()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code,$purchasedata)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_client_info(User_Name,billingemail,password,purchasedata,tokenCode) 
                                                         VALUES(:User_Name, :billingemail, :password, :purchasedata, :active_code)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->bindparam(":purchasedata",$purchasedata);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function login($email,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_client_info WHERE billingemail=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['password']==md5($upass))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['UCODE'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: index.php?error");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?error");
                exit;
            }       
        }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

any help would really be appreciated

Comment: The call to `$user_home->register()` shouldn't have a SQL query as a parameter.

Comment: your named placeholders are another issue

Comment: you're doing the same errors you did in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42219923/1415724 and no idea why you accepted the answer in there since they didn't fully solve it.

Comment: and why use md5? you're not going live with this are you?

Comment: use password_hash with salt. md5 is easily crackable

Comment: I don't see a closing `</form>` tag for your form. Make sure you closed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting value to database using prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219923/inserting-value-to-database-using-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your named placeholders:

```
(:User_Name, :billingemail, :password, :purchasedata, :active_code)
```

and

```
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
        $stmt->bindparam(":purchasedata",$purchasedata);
```

- **They don't match.**

Each named placeholder **must** match and in lettercase.

Example:

`:user_name` and `:User_Name` are **not** the same.

so here:

```
(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :purchasedata, :active_code)
```

The manual is rather explicit on this:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

and don't go live with this in using MD5, it's no longer safe.

Use `password_hash()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

**Check for errors:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

and make sure your column names are correct and lettercase could be a factor.

Comment: @sean welcome. Check for errors also, I included a few links near the bottom you can look at and use.

Comment: @sean and make sure the column names are correct in the query. You may have used the wrong column names with the placeholders. The named placeholders don't need to match the column names (that's a personal preference) but the column names must be correct and the placeholders' names must match in VALUES and the binds.

Comment: @sean you wrote: *"to update a row with an amount (INT)"* - if you want to "update" a table, you need to use `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`. If that's the case, then that's a whole different story. If you don't know how UPDATE works, it's not the same syntax as INSERT and you'll need to read the manual on that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html - make sure you started the session also, since you're using sessions.

Comment: all I want to do is place the value the user enters in the specific row. This will be set to zero again anyway. So INSERT INTO is what I should be using or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: @sean it's hard to say. If there is existing data in the table and you want to update a certain row, then you need to "UPDATE" it, not "INSERT".

Comment: @sean I also placed a comment under your question asking if you closed off your form with `</form>`. Plus, you may be wanting to insert the same values in your db with some form of (unique) constraint with an auto_increment ID row. There isn't anything else I can add to my answer or in comments. You need to take it from here and to keep on testing/debugging with the links I left in my answer.

Comment: hi, I do close form further down in the code. Thank you, for all your help. I now get this error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

But this is linked to what you pointed out earlier. I will keep at it and sort it out. Again thanks bud

Comment: @sean make sure each variable in the binds have value. You may be trying to insert the same value in the db that won't let you because of a unique constraint or primary key. It could be anything. Use `var_dump();` to check what's going in or not, you can also var_dump your query. Again, make sure the named placeholders are the same, it could also be the order they're in. Good luck, wish I could help you out more. The column types could also be an issue and for the values.

Comment: thanks man, I will let you know when I have it up and running

Comment: @sean You're welcome Sean; keep at it. I'm confident you'll get it ;-)

Comment: @sean as stated in a first comment under your question, you're doing this in one query `$user_home->register("INSERT INTO tbl_client_info....` yet your function reads as `function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code,$purchasedata)` that isn't how it works. That first INSERT is failing here and probably the first reason why you got the error. That line should probably read as `$stmt = $user_home->runQuery(....` - TBH, I've only started learning about classes recently, so you'll need to figure out that part as to how your methods should be running each query.

Comment: just wanted to leave you  a quick thanks here. I managed to get this working using  your suggested links and more. Gonna get cracking  on the password safety now.